# What's the right way to use biblatex-chicago?

Tags: biblatex-chicago

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[authordate-trad,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}


\title{A}
\author{B}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


\autocite{kamenica2011bayesian}
\textcite{kamenica2011bayesian}


\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{VD_reference}

\end{document}
```

The content of bib file is as follows:

```
@article{kamenica2011bayesian,
  title={Bayesian persuasion},
  author={Kamenica, Emir and Gentzkow, Matthew},
  journal={American Economic Review},
  volume={101},
  number={6},
  pages={2590--2615},
  year={2011}
}
```

What I would like to get is Kamenica and Gentzkow (2003) or (Kamenica and Gentzkow, 2003). The file just does not compile well. I believe I use some control sequences in a wrong way. Could you please tell me the correct ones instead? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If you use `biblatex` (naturally that also includes `biblatex-chicago`, which is a bit special because it is best used with `\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}` instead of the usual `\usepackage{biblatex}`), you must not use `\bibliographystyle` and you cannot use `\bibliography` inside the document body.

The bibliography style is decided by the style options you pass to `biblatex`, so `\bibliographystyle` is simply not needed. To tell `biblatex` which `.bib` file to use, we usually use `\addbibresource` (you could also use `\bibliography`, but that is deprecated) in the preamble. The actual bibliography is then printed with `\printbibliography`.

A document would then look like the following (I used the standard example file `biblatex-examples.bib` instead of your `VD_reference.bib` to make things more compact)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[authordate-trad,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson}
\textcite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998) Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998)]

Note that this document needs to be compiled with LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX. If you previously used BibTeX, you may have to configure your editor to run Biber for you. See [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864). [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) has some background on what Biber does. If all those "bib" terms are confusing, [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864) is a helpful read. As are [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864) and  [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864).

Comment: Thanks! The compilation looks a little bit complicated. I do not specifically want biblatex-chicago, all I need is the citation being like Author (year) or (Author, year). Is there an easier alternative?

Comment: @Ypbor As long as you want to use `biblatex` the compilation sequence is going to be the same (unless you want to use the BibTeX backend, which is not recommended). A more generic style would be `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}` instead of `\usepackage[authordate-trad,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}`. ...

Comment: ... Keep in mind that even with classical BibTeX you have to have a structurally similar compile sequence. The only difference is that you need Biber instead of BibTeX. So as long as you configure your editor properly, there is little difference between a BibTeX-based and a `biblatex`-based approach.

Comment: @Ybor By the way, if your main concern is the number of compilation commands, you might as well just try using `latexmk` which should take care of the appropriate number of latex runs for you.